# Creation AD bulks script issues

Tags: powershell

I did an Ad bulks script but doesn't seem to work for some reason. can someone help me ?

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Users\Deng\Desktop\newusers.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
$Username  = $Users.username
   $Firstname = $Users.firstname
   $Password  = $Users.password
   $Lastname  = $Users.lastname
   $OU        = $Users.ou

         New-ADUser `
        -SamAccountName $Username `
        -UserPrincipalName $Username@aptushealth.com `
        -Name $Firstname $Lastname `
        -GivenName $Firstname `
        -Surname $Lastname `
        -Enabled $True `
        -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false `
        -DisplayName $Lastname, $Firstname `
        -Path $OU `
        -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
}
```

I get this error below :

> ConvertTo-SecureString: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String'
>   because it is null. At line:24 char:54
>   + ...            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlai ...
>   +                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

also see the content of the CSV

```
usersname firstname password lastname ou
efranklin Edward P@s$word Franklin "OU=PII Users,DC=PII,DC=net"
bjackson Bill P@s$word Jackson "OU=PII Users,DC=PII,DC=net"
```

I have made the change and this is what i get – DavidNG

ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null. At line:24 char:54 + ... -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlai ... –

still getting the same error

Comment: What is `$Users`?

Comment: @Caramiriel $users is the variable to define users in the csv

Comment: I think @Caramiriel 's point is it should be $User, because that's what you specified in the ForEach

Comment: I'm starting to think your input CSV file is not a CSV file at all, but a text file in the exact (list) format as you show us here. Please edit your question and add the first three or four lines of the inputfile to show what it truly looks like.

Comment: 1st line : usersname firstname password lastname ou

Comment: 2nt line : efranklin Edward P@s$word Franklin  "OU=PII Users,DC=PII,DC=net"

Comment: @theo i did created a Csv utf 8

Comment: I have edited your question to put that in as readable, formatted text. Am I correct in thinking the CSV uses a space character as field delimiter? In that case simply add this to the `Import-Csv` cmdlet as parameter `-Delimiter ' '` and take the advice from @Steven to use Splatting to get rid of those horrible backticks.

Comment: Extra note that now it seems your original headername `username` suddenly is `usersname` (there's a extra `s` in it as plural)

Comment: @Theo i don't understand who do mean username is usersname ?

Comment: sorry i see. i have corrected it

Comment: @Theo i did the correction and still getting the same error `-AccountPassword (convertto-securestring "$Password" -AsPlai ...`

Comment: `ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\deng\OneDrive - Aptus Health\Script\test.ps1:24 char:54
+ ...          -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring "$Password" -AsPlai ...`

Comment: I see you posted this same question again, but again you show a different style for the input file. So, which is it.. Like it shows in this question? Try to make it easy for anyone, including yourself by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60547710/edit) your question and copy/paste the **EXACT** input csv. Don't try to modify, just sanitize so we don't see real user names and such,

Comment: Sorry but i don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: In that case... Please first learn about [CSV files](https://www.howtogeek.com/348960/what-is-a-csv-file-and-how-do-i-open-it/), what they look like, how you can open them in Notepad to copy the top 3 lines to paste in a question. While you are at it, please also have a look at [How to format code ans preformatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake that in foreach loop you operating by object `$user` **not** `$users`, so you must write:

```
   $Username  = $User.username
   $Firstname = $User.firstname
   $Password  = $User.password
   $Lastname  = $User.lastname
   $OU        = $User.ou
```

Import-Csv read file row by row so first row must contains names of column like:

```
username;firstname;password;lastname;ou
```

Then might be your data:

```
efranklin;Edward;P@s$word;Franklin;"OU=PII Users,DC=PII,DC=net"
```

**Additional**
You must have something like that(**and don't forget in csv file must be ';' delimiter!!!!!** separating parameters):

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Users\Deng\Desktop\newusers.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($User in $ADUsers){
   $Username  = $User.username
   $Firstname = $User.firstname
   $Password  = $User.password
   $Lastname  = $User.lastname
   $OU        = $User.ou
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Username -UserPrincipalName ($Username+'@aptushealth.com') -Name ($Firstname+' '+$Lastname) -GivenName $Firstname -Surname $Lastname -Enabled $True -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -DisplayName ($Lastname+' '+$Firstname) -Path $OU -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force)            
}
```

Comment: I have made the change and this is what i get

Comment: ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At line:24 char:54
+ ...            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlai ...

Comment: You must edit you post question and show what is your actually code and first 3 row in your csv file

Comment: Vad. --- The default delimiter is a comma for csv, not semicolon with quoted strings. Hence 'comma separate value' file type. You can use a semicolon, etc, but then you need to specifically pass the -Delimiter switch to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some additional advice.

In your original code you were assigning the wrong values.  As several participants have mentioned (see @Vad [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60548020/4749264)) $Users would have been null in the code you submitted.  It makes sense that would cause an error that specifically cites a null value.  The error is very literal ConvertTo-SecureString will not accept a null value for the -String Parameter.

You used the iteration variable $User but made variable assignments like:

```
$Password = $Users.password
```

$User**s** (notice the "s") would be null in your sample and you should use `$User.password` instead!

Now, if you did all that and you are still getting the error.  My advice would be to step back and check the data before executing `New-ADUser` .  I'd first comment out `New-ADUser` . Then you can perform checks like:

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\Users\Deng\Desktop\newusers.csv
$ADUsers | Where-Object($_.Password -eq $null) | Format-Table
```

That would give you all the objects with a null password property.  Those would need to be fixed before you try to use the content as input to `New-ADUser` .

Note: You can also use Excel for this  sort of checking.

Password is just one of the properties. I would repeat the test citing other properties in the `Where{}` clause. You have to make sure the data is completely clean!

---

Original comments supplemental to other answers:

I think this has already been answered, but for readability I think this is a good use case for splatting the parameters.

Untested Example:

```
$ADUsers = Import-Csv C:\Users\Deng\Desktop\newusers.csv

foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    $Params =
    @{
        samAccountName        = $User.username
        UserPrincipalName     = ($User.username + '@aptushealth.com')
        GivenName             = $User.FirstName
        SurName               = $User.LastName
        Name                  = ($User.FirstName + ' ' + $User.lastname)
        DisplayName           = ($User.lastname + ' ' + $User.FirstName)
        Enabled               = $true
        Path                  = $User.ou
        AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.password -AsPlainText -Force)
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false

    }

    New-ADUser @Params
}
```

This saves you from all the back tick escaping which is generally considered hazardous.

Comment: @DavidNG Please, if you want to comment on an answer, do it as **comment**. Do not try to edit the answer with remarks.